# What is a more efficient way to get the first match from a reverse file search using some combination of awk grep and sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am working on an operating system with limited utilities.  Utilities like tail, head, and tac are not available! sed, awk, and Grep are available, but grep does not have the -m option for stopping after the first find. see the list of available options [here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/qnxcar2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities%2Ftopic%2Fg%2Fgrep.html).

My goal is to search for a line containing a string in a potentially large log.txt file, maybe  ~100Mb from the end in reverse and print it. The trick is the operation has to be fast: no more than 3-4sec tops.

I tried using sed to reverse the contents of the file into another and then using awk and grep in a loop to search chunks of 10,000 lines, but the sed reverse was way too slow for anything beyond a few Mb

Something I tried.

```py
self.sed_line_search = 10001
self.sed_cmd = "sed -e :a -e '$q;N;"+str(self.sed_line_search)+",$D;ba'"
self.awk_cmd = "awk '/Version/{print}'"   
self.Command = self.sed_cmd + " " + LOGFILE_PATH + " | " + self.awk_cmd + "\n"
tries, max_tries = 1,5
while tries < max_tries:
    ret = execute(self.Command)
    if not ret:
        self.sed_line_search += 10000
        self.sed_cmd = "sed -e :a -e '$q;N;"+str(self.sed_line_search)+",$D;ba'"
        self.Command = self.sed_cmd + " " + LOGFILE_PATH + " | " + self.awk_cmd + "\n"
        tries += 1
```

With out knowing how to stop at the fist match without the grep -m 1 option, this slightly achieves that goal by only looking at a few thousand lines at a time. But, It does not search in reverse.

Comment: *the first match from a reverse file search* -- is that a long way of saying the *last* match in a file?

Comment: Yeah, classic case of describing **how** you think something needs to be done rather than describing **what** it is that needs to be done.

Comment: I would like at using `split` to divide the file into smaller pieces and then use `rev` plus `gawk`. Also, according to the GNX docs, `tail` is available, so I would definitely use that.

Comment: @Shawn: _the last match in the file_ suggests to me that I have to search the entire file returning the last match. performing the operation in reverse returning the first match just seems more efficient.

Comment: @Marco: omg! tail is available. ok I will try a out some solutions with tail. In the mean time. I know the first issue I will run into here is that I want to return the last match in the file. using tail I can specify something like 'the last 10000 lines and grep for the string, but I want only the last one.

Comment: Having tail available is not useful unless your target string is almost always in the last N thousand lines of the file because the time it takes to repeatedly spin up a shell to run tail + head (which you'll need after the first iteration to avoid re-selecting the last N thousand lines) in in a loop will outweigh any benefit they could provide in creating a smaller sample to run `grep` on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the fastest you could do would be:

```
grep 'regexp' | sed -n '$p'
```

Comment: I like this answer, very simple.let me wrestle around with my regular expression and it just may be the accepted answer.

Comment: trying this one out and getting any output from: `grep -e '^.*\b(str_to_find)\b.*$' Log.txt | sed -n '$p'` and ideas?

Comment: `\b` is a GNU grep extension unlikely to work in whetever limited grep you're using so that's probably your real issue. Additionally though - `.*` means `zero-or-many` so surrounding str_to_find with `^.*(` and `).*$` adds no value - if str_to_find exists then the line will be printed with or without those adornments. str_to_find implies you want to find a string rather than a regexp - if so you should use `grep -F` instead of just `grep`. If you add ed sample input and expected output to your question we could help you figure out how to write a regexp.

Comment: Wow ok, Thanks Ed for the clarification and answer!: winning candidate: `grep -F str_to_find Log.txt | sed -n '$p'`.  Jotne's solution took 37 sec on a 138Mb file. Your solution on the same file took 9 sec.

Comment: Your welcome. Jotne's populating an array because the way you phrased your question made it sound like you wanted to output multiple values in reverse rather than just output the last value. Please try the equivalent script for just printing out one last value which I'll now post in a comment below his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it this you want.  It search for all line with test and prints them in reveres.

```
cat file
dfsdf
test1
fsdfsdf
fdg
sfdgs
fdgsdf
gsfdg
sfdte
test2
dgsfdgsdf
fdgsfdg
sdfgs
df
test3
sfdgsfdg

awk '/test/ {a[++x]=$0} END {for (i=x;i>=1;i--) print a[i]}' file
test3
test2
test1
```

Comment: I like this answer best (regular expressions are not my cup of tea...).  Can you think of a way to clip the output after the first value?  I only need the last match in the file.

Comment: wrt `I like this answer best (regular expressions are not my cup of tea...)` - hopefully you understand it's using the same regular expression as all of the other answers, Jotne just named it `test` instead of `regexp` in his code.

Comment: @cogito please try `awk '/test/{a=$0} END{if (a!="") print a}' file`. I don't expect it to be as fast as the `grep | sed` approach but it'll be closer than populating and iterating on an array which was only done because your question sounded like you wanted multiple values output in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/regexp/h;$!b;x;p' file
```

Copy the line that matches regexp to the hold space and at the end of the file print the hold space.